How to hide a popover when clicking outside of it
In my web page, I have a popover that shows information from a remote URL, this way:
$('*[data-poload]').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var e=$(this);
    $.get(e.data('poload'), function(d) {
        var titulo = d.title + ' - ' + moment(d.sentWhen).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
        var texto = d.text;
        e.popover({title: titulo, content: texto}).popover('show');
    });
});

This is the A tag:

<a href="#" tabindex="0" data-bs-placement="auto" data-poload="the_remote_link">

With that code, the popover is shown, but when clicking outside of it or in another popover, previous one is not hidden.
How can I do it?
